# django-allauth: how to modify email confirmation url?

Tags: python, django, email, nginx, django-allauth

I'm running django on port 8001, while nginx is handling webserver duties on port 80.  nginx proxies views and some REST api calls to Django.  I'm using django-allauth for user registration/authentication.

When a new user registers, django-allauth sends the user an email with a link to click.  Because django is running on port 8001, the link looks like `http://machine-hostname:8001/accounts/confirm-email/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

How can I make the url look like `http://www.example.com/accounts/confirm-email/xxxxxxxx` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django get hostname and port from HTTP headers. 
Add `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` into your nginx configuration before options `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Thanks; will try this when I get a chance next.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and also found that ferrangb's solution had no effect on outgoing allauth emails.  mr_tron's answer got me halfway, but I had to do a little bit more:

1) In nginx configuration, put

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host
```

before options proxy_pass.

2) In `settings.py`, add the domain name to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.  I also added the www version of my domain name, since I get traffic to both addresses.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'example.com', 'www.example.com']
```

And, of course, restart nginx and gunicorn or whatever is serving your Django.  With the first step but not the second, all hits to the site were instant 400 errors (unless `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`.)