# nginx blancer config upstream

Tags: nginx

I have 2 nodes files and user anther server blancer of them.

My config:

```
worker_processes 40;

events {
    worker_connections 2000;

}

http {


   upstream backend {

        server 192.168.1.44:80;
   }

    server {
    listen *:80;


        server_name 5.9.XX.XX  ;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is when I try to work it not get any data but when I try to use:

```
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.44:80;
```

it's working good.

I am confused. Where is the problem?

it's fixed when i try use port 8080 with upstream working but i have problem some urls 404 redirect with port 8080 not 80

Comment: May be problem, with hostname which sending to backend. Try `        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host "192.168.1.44";
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }`

Comment: it's fixed when i try use port 8080 with upstream
working but i have problem some urls 404 redirect with port 8080 not 80

Comment: what service was listen port 8080? nginx? backend? may be something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/24128433/3346514